# Adding comma between array items except for last (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to list authors for a certain category on Wordpress and I'm having trouble inserting a comma between each item, except for the last.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
 if (is_category() || is_tag()) {
  $at_least = 1;
  $author_array = list_author_in_this_cat ($at_least);
  foreach (array_slice($author_array, 0, 10) as $author):
   $name = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
   $link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
   echo "<a href='/author/".$link."'>".$name."";
  endforeach;
 }
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with just joining them?

Comment: Get all items except the last one (use `array_slice()`), `implode()` it with a `,`, and concatenate the result with the last item.

Comment: See: http://us2.php.net/array_map + http://us3.php.net/implode

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$nameArray = array();
foreach (array_slice($author_array, 0, 10) as $author):
    $name = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
    $link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
    $nameArray[] = "<a href='/author/".$link."'>".$name."";
endforeach;

echo implode(',', $nameArray);
```

This will put each author entry into an array; when you echo it out, you're merging the array using commas as the glue.

Comment: Andrewski, having a problem that I didn't realize previously.  Rather than linking to the author.php, it is linking to "localhost:8888/author/author-name".  Any thoughts on how I can get it to link to the author page?

Comment: If that's all you need, you should be able to fix it by changing the `href` to whatever you need - `href="/author/author.php"`, or wherever you need to link to.